Congratulations! Bitcoin is graduating!
You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Bitcoin met our threshold for graduation-worthy sites and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.
What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - in light of the recent stepdown of Nick ODell as a moderator, these will actually be starting today.
You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
You will soon be able to select your own community ads. We're very close to the new year and the new ad cycle, so we'll be holding those off until December.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to give you the things we could give you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on Meta Stack Exchange using the [graduating-sites] tag.
This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

In light of the pending design upgrade, I would like to encourage people to contribute to the discussion here: What should this site's name be when we get our new design?

Finally! Well deserved, Bitcoin.SE! Good work!

Congratulations all.  Note those of us who held $1000 in bitcoin when this SE began will now have $3,000,000 in bitcoin!  Well done all!

Congratulations Bitcoin.SE, @Murch, and the new moderators!
